# How to sort a list of alphanumeric strings in one or more conditions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of filenames that I need to put in certain order to perform some operations.The filenames are alphanumeric strings and are in a list like below

```
lis = ["8_19_dm12_file", "3_19_dm14_file", "8_19_dm9_file", "2_19_dm1_file", "3_19_dm2_file"]
```

Now I need to sort them first on the basis of first digit in ascending order and then sort them on the basis of last digit in ascending order.Something like below

```
 lis = ["2_19_dm1_file", "3_19_dm2_file", "3_19_dm14_file", "8_19_dm9_file", "8_19_dm12_file"]
```

Currently I am able to do this separately.I am able to sort based on the first digit by doing something like this

```
lis.sort(key=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])

['2_19_dm1_file', '3_19_dm14_file', "3_19_dm2_file" '8_19_dm12_file', '8_19_dm9_file']
```

In a seperate operation, I am able to sort on the basis of last digit by doing something like this

```
lis.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+', x.split("_")[2])[0]))

['2_19_dm1_file', "3_19_dm2_file" '8_19_dm9_file', '8_19_dm12_file', '3_19_dm14_file']
```

But if I run these two operations together, my list again gets jumbled up.How do I ensure I am able to sort on the basis of my requirement?

Comment: Do you know that in your current sorting '16_' will precede '6_'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
lst = ["8_19_dm12_file", "3_19_dm14_file", "8_19_dm9_file", "2_19_dm1_file", "3_19_dm2_file"]

def orderer(x):
    s = x.split('_')
    return list(map(int, s[:2])) + [int(s[2][2:])]

lst_sorted = sorted(lst, key=orderer)

# ['2_19_dm1_file', '3_19_dm2_file', '3_19_dm14_file', '8_19_dm9_file', '8_19_dm12_file']
```

Comment: This is what I wanted.Thanks!